# Как заблокировать закрытие командной строки пользователем? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

То есть сделать крестик неактивным, на определённый промежуток времени. (Python 3). Нужно чтобы работало на Windows. На других OS необязательно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На английском SO задан абсолютно аналогичный, по моему скромному мнению, вопрос: ["Prevent Python shell close"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892735/prevent-python-shell-close). Ниже привожу собственноручный перевод принятого там ответа.

В общем случае - это невозможно.

Окно терминала, вообще говоря, это отдельный от интерпретатора python процесс (верно для обычной программы в консоли, но может быть по-другому, например, в случае с IPython и т.д.). Если консоль получила команду закрываться, то (с точки зрения популярных ОС и оконных менеджеров) взять и как-то предотвратить это не получится, ведь это совершенно другая программа, она лишь обеспечивает ввод/вывод.

Однако, вы можете оставить свою программу запущенной после закрытия консоли. Консоль все равно закроется, но программа останется работать в фоне.

***

далее идут замечания про unix-подобные системы, но вывод напрашивается однозначный - невозможно.

PS: Сделать неактивной кнопку закрытия у окна совершенно любой программы, не имеющей отношения к запущенному интерпретатору python, скорее всего, по аналогичным причинам тоже не получится.